# How do you connect a local git to a bitbucket repository

Tags: git, passwords, push, bitbucket

To Preface: I just started learning git this week, so assume nothing.

That said, I have successfully completed the following commands

**I've set up my local directory**

```
mkdir /treehouse_repo
cd /treehouse_repo
git init
git remote add origin https://mkov88@bitbucket.org/mkov88/treehouse-portfolio-site.git
```

**I've set up my local directory**

```
mkdir /treehouse_repo
cd /treehouse_repo
git init
git remote add origin URL
```

**I've created my first file and commit**

```
echo "mkov88" >> contributors.txt
git add contributors.txt
git commit -m 'Initial commit with contributors'
```

**Here's where I'm getting stuck**:

When I try to push it via

```
git push -u origin master
```

the next line says:

```
Password for 'https://mkov88@bitbucket.org':<br>
```

I can type anything and the cursor just sits there.
if I push enter it says:

```
fatal: authentication failed for 'URL'
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

**update**
I tried to add a .basche file in my home directory with the following code

```
SSH_ENV=$HOME/.ssh/environment

# start the ssh-agent
function start_agent {
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
    # spawn ssh-agent
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add
}

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi
```

still getting asked for a password

Comment: Just to be clear, the ssh agent has nothing to do with https, and would help only if a/ you were using a remote url with ssh, and b/ if your private ssh key was passphrase-protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I  can type anything and the cursor just sits there.

That doesn't sound surprising, considering the password input is usually hidden

> if I push enter it says

```
fatal: authentication failed for 'URL'
```

That would only happen if what you just typed isn't the password of the account `mkov88` on bitbucket.org.